# window.open a new page and .click a link in the new page - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open

OK so I'm opening a new tab on delay with the following:

```
setTimeout(function(){x=window.open('http://sample.com');}, 1000);
```

On that new page there is a link I would like to click after the window opens. I'm able to open the browser dev tools and input this to click the link I want:

```
$('.view-public')[0].click();
```

I would like to open the window then apply the click on delay, so I've tried to combine what I have as such:

```
setTimeout(function(){x=window.open('http://sample.com');}, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){x.$('.view-public')[0].click(); }, 3000);
```

However this is giving me the "SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin..." which I have looked up and understand, however it seems most people who encounter this are working with an iframe, I'm not using an iframe just want to open a new window and click a specific link. Is there any solution to this or way around this?

Comment: Do you control http://sample.com? I would not be surprised if the browser is correctly preventing you from accessing outside controls. Random example situation: Journalist clicks on interesting article. Article JS takes control, opens a new tab, goes to Twitter . com, clicks the entry form, inserts something horrible, and clicks Tweet. So yeah, it sounds like a security thing.

Comment: I don't control sample.com, I'm trying to automate a task. If I can do part A just fine and part B just fine there has to be a way to do A & B together right?

Comment: If your code is on the same website (sample.com), you can control the pages. Otherwise, you will hit cross site scripting security blocks as Katana314 noted and with a normal browser, there is no way through that.

Comment: @RyanLitwiller - if you are trying to automate something, lets take the example of maybe a webdriver for testing harness etc  Then the approach to take would be to drive BOTH components via the webdriver as part of the test or automation.  Otherwise you are rightly getting caught in cross origin issues.  The only other issue would be a browser extension, which again is essentially driving at a browser level via something you as the user explicitly enabled... not driving their page via your page.

Comment: Thanks @NickSharp Webdriver might do the trick. JavaScriptDude you said with a normal browser, are there any alternatives like maybe a command line browser?

Comment: @RyanLitwiller - you might want to take a look at Casper.js http://casperjs.org/ which was pretty much built for this type of testing and automation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a chrome browser plug-in that is allowing me to accomplish what I want.

[Custom JavaScript](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija)

I'm performing the new window opening with JS on my site and with the plugin I can create custom scripts to run on specified websites. So Custom JS is performing the click for me.

Its a bit of a hack but its giving me the result I need.